# Query of MySQL database it does not work correctly with if conditional?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, if-statement

I want to select value from MySQL database, and if the value equal to `wait` then print something. It is simple thing, but the conditional it does not work correctly.

code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'DAGtest2'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Database Connected!');
});

connection.query("SELECT `message` FROM `counter` LIMIT 1", (err, check) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(check);

    if (check['message'] === "wait"){
        console.log("waiting....");

    } else {
        console.log("start counter...."); 
    }
});
```

output:

```
Database Connected!
[ RowDataPacket { message: 'wait' } ]
start counter....
```

and if I delete the `wait` message is still show me the same output:

```
Database Connected!
[]
start counter....
```

I have tried to use unequal conditional:

```
if (check['message'] !== "wait"){
    console.log("waiting....");

} else {
    console.log("start counter...."); 
}
```

The output:

```
Database Connected!
[ RowDataPacket { message: 'wait' } ]
waiting....
```

and If I delete the `wait` as well:

```
Database Connected!
[]
waiting....
```

The correct output I want is when message is equal to `wait`, it must print `waiting....` and else it must print `start counter....`. But the code it doesn't work correctly when I delete `wait` from table.

How could solve it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Would reworking your sql statement to something more like this work for you?

```
SELECT message
CASE
    WHEN message = 'wait' THEN 'waiting....'
    ELSE 'start counter....'
END
FROM counter;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately,  I need it in node.js because there are lines after `console.log()` but I deleted it to make it simple for now.